# Can I use GhostDoc to add documentation to an entire class or code file?

Tags: visual-studio, ghostdoc

I love GhostDoc, but I want to be able to "Document This" for an entire file, and not just one member at a time.  Is this possible?

Comment: I did not re-install ghost doc on my recently acquired machine.  I tried it.  Didn't like it.  R# did a better job of "ghost writing" the generic comments AND they pass stylecop formatting.

Comment: You can actually do that now with GhostDoc Pro - it introduces Document File, Document Type commands and flexible T4 based comment templates

Comment: You can't use GhostDoc to add documentation, period. All it does is add pointless file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  I still love it also regardless.

Comment: This is no longer correct. GhostDoc Pro has a 'Document File' menu option.

Answer (score 3):

When I originally answered this question, this was not possible in GhostDoc, or in my (similar) addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/)).

*(This was an intentional design choice in Atomineer, and presumably also in GhostDoc, because it's a generally bad idea to document everything automatically and move on. Both these addins produce a reasonable starting point for documentation of a method, and sometimes they will provide good enough documentation that you don't need to make any adjustments - but most of the time you will want to tweak the resulting comment. If you auto-generate the entire documentation set, then the docs will be pretty poor, because they will do little more than describing what the code element names already state).*

**However**, both addins now now provide this feature, which is very useful in the following situations:

- (in Atomineer) To batch-convert legacy comments between JavaDoc, Doxygen, Qt and XML Documentation formats
- (in Atomineer) To update the style/layout of documentation comments after changing the AtomineerUtils formatting options
- (in both addins) To quickly add skeleton documentation to a class

In all these situations it is strongly recommended that you review the resulting comments, but automating the update does save a lot of time.

Comment: "sometimes they will provide good enough documentation that you don't need to make any adjustments"  Based on my experience using GhostDoc and using libraries "commented" with it, I think instead of *sometimes* you meant to say *never*.

Comment: Two things. 1) it IS possible in GhostDoc now, and 2) it would be good to state that you are the developer of AtomineerUtils

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - You're quite right on both counts. I normally do try to make that clear. I've edited mny answer to bring it up to date with recent developments.

Answer (score 1):

Use document File Option:

[image]

see the comment added for all members within the file:

[image]